# Why is pcregrep faster than grep?

Tags: grep, centos, pcregrep

I have some large text file(3 GB rails log file) on a centos os **with a corrupted byte in this text file**. When trying to search some pattern using grep, it runs indefinitely and I have to close it, however with pcregrep it takes less than a minute, so any clue why this difference ?

My search using grep:

```
grep -Pzo "2016-04-20(.*?)SomeController#index" production.log | wc -l
```

using pcregrep:

```
pcregrep -M "2016-04-20(.*?)SomeController#index" production.log | wc -l
```

Comment: The algorithm used in `pcregrep` could be more faster for this specific pattern. It may skip more bytes than the algorithm used in `grep` in the case of a mis-match.

Comment: Your are using different pattern with `grep` and `pcregrep`. For true comparison, use the same pattern.